# Error after add plugin simple_permissions on pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I tried using the simple_permissions plugin and then I got an error to migrate to androidX even though I had migrated to androidX and after I deleted android.Jetifier at gradle.property I didn't get any more errors and the plugin was successfully used. Why did it happen? Will my project get a problem in the future? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all your packages in the pubspec.yaml are of the latest version. Then open the android project of your flutter app with android studio, select Refactor->Migrate to Androidx. Wait until android studio finishes migrating your project, rebuild your project. Hope it helps!